# Jogo da adivinha com 3 níveis de dificuldade

Tags: javascript

Estou a tentar criar um jogo da adivinha com 3 níveis com introdução num prompt mas estou a ter um problema com a escolha dos níveis, independentemente do valor introduzido no prompt, o nível que corre sempre é o 1º.
Apenas vou deixar o código até à segunda condição, para poupar espaço.

```
var nivel = 10 ;
var random = (Math.random(nivel));
var multiply = random * nivel;
var round = Math.round(multiply) ;
var number = round;

  for ( i=1; i<=3; i++ ) {
    var escolhaNivel = prompt("escolhe um nível entre 1, 2 ou 3");
      if ( escolhaNivel = "1" ) {
        nivel = nivel
      } else if ( escolhaNivel = "2" ) {
        nivel = 100
      } else if ( escolhaNivel = "3" ) {
        nivel = 100000
      } else{
        alert( "Escolhe entre 1 a 3!" );
      }


if(nivel === nivel) {
    

  var guess = prompt( "Qual é o número que pensei entre 1 e 10?" );

   if( guess < number) { 

   alert( "Maior! Qual é o número? " + "Tentativas restantes: " + (3-i) );

  
  } else if( guess < number) { 

    alert( "Maior! Qual é o número? " + "Tentativas restantes: " + (3-i) );

  } else if ( guess > number ) {

    alert( "Menor! Qual é o número? " + "Tentativas restantes: " + (3-i) );

  } else {

    alert( " Muito bem! Acertaste no número! " + number );
  }

}

else if(nivel === nivel2) {

var guess = prompt( "Qual é o número que pensei entre 1 e 100?" );

 if( guess < number) { 

 alert( "Maior! Qual é o número? " + "Tentativas restantes: " + (3-i) );


} else if( guess < number) { 

  alert( "Maior! Qual é o número? " + "Tentativas restantes: " + (3-i) );

} else if ( guess > number ) {

  alert( "Menor! Qual é o número? " + "Tentativas restantes: " + (3-i) );

} else {

  alert( " Muito bem! Acertaste no número! " + number );
}

}
```

Comment: `nivel === nivel` sempre será `true` independente do valor de `nivel` e `nivel = nivel` não altera o valor de `nivel`.

Comment: Além do que foi dito no comentário acima, você está atribuindo um valor dentro do `if (escolhaNivel = "1")`, o correto seria fazer comparação com `===` ao invés de `=` (que é uma atribuição de valor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peço desculpa pela demora a responder mas acabei por conseguir fazer o que queria. Vou deixar o código em baixo. Um abraço!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>Jogo da Adivinha</title> 
</head>
<body> 
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
 while(true){    
     var nivelEscolhido = prompt("Escolhe um nível entre 1, 2 e 3");
     var tentativas = 1;
     var check = false;
         if (nivelEscolhido == 1){ 
             var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
             while (tentativas <= 3){
                 var guess = prompt("Insere um número entre 0 e 10");
                 if (number == guess){
                     alert("Parabéns, acertaste no número em " +tentativas+ " tentativas!");
                     check = true;
                     break;
                 }
                 else if (number > guess){
                     alert("O meu número é maior que o teu!");
                 }
                 else if (number < guess){
                     alert("O meu número é menor que o teu!");
                 }
                 tentativas++;
             }
             if (check == false){
                 alert("GAME OVER");
             }
         }
         else if (nivelEscolhido == 2){
             var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
             while (tentativas <= 3){
                 var guess = prompt("Insere um número entre 0 e 100");
                 if (number == guess){
                     alert("Parabéns, acertaste no número em " +tentativas+ " tentativas!");
                     check = true;
                     break;
                 }
                 else if (number > guess){
                     alert("O meu número é maior que o teu!");
                 }
                 else if (number < guess){
                     alert("O meu número é menor que o teu!");
                 }
                 tentativas++;   
             }
             if (check == false){
                 alert("GAME OVER");
             }
         }

         else if (nivelEscolhido == 3){
             var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100001);
             while (tentativas <= 6){
                 var guess = prompt("Insere um número entre 0 e 100000");
                 if (number == guess){
                     alert("Parabéns, acertaste no número em " +tentativas+ " tentativas!");
                     check = true;
                     break;
                 }
                 else if (number > guess){
                     alert("O meu número é maior que o teu!");
                 }
                 else if (number < guess){
                     alert("O meu número é menor que o teu!");
                 }
                 tentativas++;
             }
             if (check == false){
                 alert("GAME OVER");
             }
         }
 }
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, SuRGE! Tudo bem?

Eu faria este código com o uso de funções.
Deixei comentado pra ficar melhor compreendido. :-)
Me avisa se deu certo!

Abraço!

```
function geral() {

    //aqui o prompt vai chamar uma função que recebe como argumento o nível 
    //escolhido pelo user:
    var nivelEscolhido = level(prompt('Escolha um nível entre 1 e 3'));

    //essa função recebe o nível escolhido e com algumas condicionais
    //retorna a chamada para outra função com o argumento do nível:
    function level(nivel) {
        if (nivel == 1) {
            return jogo(nivel);
        }

        if (nivel == 2) {
            jogo(nivel);
            return jogo(nivel);
        }

        if (nivel == 3) {
            jogo(nivel);
            return jogo(nivel);
        }
    };

    //essa função chama o jogo propriamente dito e coloca o usuário no
    //nível escolhido:
    function jogo(nivel) {
        //muita atenção aqui: use só 2 sinais de = pois o resultado do 
        //prompt é uma string. Se usar === não vai funcionar. 
        if (nivel == 1) {
            //teu código do nível um aqui
            console.log('código nivel 1')
            return;
        }
        if (nivel == 2) {
            //teu código do nível dois aqui
            console.log('código nivel 2')
            return;
        }
        if (nivel == 3) {
            //teu código do nível três aqui
            console.log('código nivel 3')
            return;
        }
    }

};geral();
```

Comment: Boa noite, muito obrigado, já resolveu o problema de ler o valor do nível, mas agora depois de tentar adivinhar pela primeira vez o prompt fecha e não faz o jogo em si. Abraço!

Comment: Bom dia suRGE! Se possível posta teu código completo aqui ou no Github para que possamos ver o projeto como um todo. Abraço!